# How to go back to previous viewcontroller, when dimissing modal view controller

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uinavigationbar, modalviewcontroller

I am trying to go back to the previous view controller, when I am dismissing the current modal controller.

I have view controllers 1, 2, 3
1 is the root controller.

1 pushes to 2.
2 then creates a new navigation controller and puts 3 in it, then presents the navigation controller modally.

Now in 3, I have a `barbuttonitem` called `cancel`, that when it is clicked, it does:

```
this.NavigationController.DismissViewController(true, null);
```

But the problem is that after it is dismissed, it goes back to 1(root), when I want to go back to 2.

How can I solve this. I am not using storyboard for this project.

Comment: Have you tried not using the NavigationController and just going this.DismissViewController(true, null) from the VC rather than the NC

Comment: I'm confused slightly by your question.

1 is a UIViewController, 2 is a UINavigationController, 3 is a UIViewController inside 2. By pushing 2, your getting (2 as navigation, 3 as the the content). You want to remove the content, and return to 2 just a blank navigation controller?

Comment: Basically "1", is a view controller with a table full of settings, i click on a editprofile and push to "2", in "2", i click my profile picture and then modally show the media picker, to choose a photo. After I choose the photo, the picker dismisses but then goes back to 1. I want to go back to 2.